# How can I evaluate the following limit-integral combination?

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Can you give me some hint on how to show that
$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^\infty \exp(-y\cosh (x))\text dx}{\log y}=-1?$$

I tried to delimit from above and from below the function $x\mapsto−y\cosh(x)$ with some simple functions (simple means for which I can explicitly evaluate the integral by anti-differentiation) whose integrals from 0 to ∞ are asymptotic to $-\log y$ as $y$ approaches $0+$. But I failed in finding them.

Comment: Which variable is being integrated, $x$ or $y$?

Comment: @abiessu, it's x, I checked it numerically.

Comment: @Tyroshipleasurebarge: does the limit hold if $y$ was misspelled as $x$ there?

Comment: @abiessu, no it doesn't, plus taking the limit of the dummy variable wouldn't make sense anyways.

Comment: @Tyroshipleasurebarge: ah, good point

Comment: @User: please let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: @abiessu I tried to delimit from above and from below the function $x\mapsto -y\cosh(x)$ with some simple functions (simple means for which I can explicitly evaluate the integral by anti-differentiation) whose integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is asymptotic to $\log y$ as $y$ approaches $0^+$.  But I failed in finding them.
Ah, sorry for having forgotten the $dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky problem. By using the change of variable $x=\text{arccosh}(u)$ we are left with:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-yu}}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du=e^{-y}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-yu}}{\sqrt{u(u+2)}}\,du\tag{1} $$
hence we just need to study the asymptotic behaviour of the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(u+2)}}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin. It is well-known that:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(u+2)}}\right) = e^y\,K_0(y), \tag{2}$$
where $K_0$ is a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). You can recover the asymptotic form by applying a modified form of Laplace method: as [stated by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties), too (last line before the *"Properties"* paragraph) if $y$ is in a right neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ K_0(y)\approx-\log\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-\gamma \tag{3}$$
and the result follows.